# Evaluation of an Infinite Converging Sum

Tags: summation

I was asked to find the value of the following summation.

$$
x=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^j}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^k}
$$

I "solved" it approximately by expanding a few of the terms for each of the summations and finding the fraction that each of them appears to converge on, which resulted in

$$
x=1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{11}{4}
$$

But I am told that this is not correct. Even if it were, my method feels shaky. What is a more solid mathematical way to do this?

---

EDIT: After having [plugged my expression into WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bsum(1%2F2%5Ei%2B1%2F3%5Ei%2B1%2F5%5Ei%2C+for+i+%3D+1+to+infinity)), it seems that my answer is correct after all. But I'm still interested in knowing if there's a better way.

Comment: Each of the series you have given is a geometric series, which has a well-known formula for its sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $1+x+x^2+\cdots = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$, with $|x| < 1$

Comment: It is important to note that the series above do not contain the $x^0$ term. Simply subtracting $1$ gives $$x+x^2+x^3+\dots=\frac{x}{1-x}$$ for $|x|\lt1$.